# DriverManager.getConnection() failes

Tags: java, android, jdbc

In my Class DBcon which is Async i connect to a Database

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
```

works just fine in the `doInBackground()` method
however, when i try it in another method it does not work

```
public void login() throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "login: failed");
        }
}
```

It failes at `Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);`

Error:

```
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1830)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:430)
W/System.err:     at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:268)
W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:580)
W/System.err:     at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
W/System.err:     at de.egeplast.logistikscanner.DBcon.login(DBcon.java:212)
W/System.err:     at de.egeplast.logistikscanner.Honeywell$3.onClick(Honeywell.java:138)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
W/System.err:     at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1194)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28309)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:952)
```

url, user, pass are right

Comment: Please provide the full exception stacktrace. As an aside, you really shouldn't use JDBC drivers from Android. It usually doesn't perform well, is relatively insecure, and recent versions of JDBC drivers don't always work because they use features of Java not available on Android. Instead, use a REST service to mediate between your Android application and the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a similar issue just put it into another thread...

```
public void login() throws SQLException {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        
        } catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "login: failed");
        }
}
};
}
```